# Creating Postman like client in Spring Boot Oauth2

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have Resource server and Authorization server, both are working fine when I use Postman to generate to token from authorization server and then use Get request with that token, and then I see the text in my Resource server.

Is there way to create similar Client application in Spring Boot to fill the same function as postman does? Checks if user has token, if not then sends me to Authorization server where user can login, and then takes the user back with the token to see the message what is on Resource server.

Answer (score 0):

A tutorial which explains oauth2 configuration in spring boot is directly from spring pages available: [Spring Boot OAuth Tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/)